# How to pass a list to the filter_poi function in r?

Tags: r, point-clouds, lidar, lidr

I have a list of treeID which has cloud points that are less than 100. i dont want these treeID in my lidar data. How can i pass the list to the filter_poi in the lidr library to remove these cloud points.

```
las_i <- filter_poi(las,treeID != 2)
```

Here i will get las data without the treeID 2. But instead of only 2 i want to pass all the treeID in my list to the filter_poi.

list = [1,6]

I could do something like

```
las <- filter_poi(las, (treeID != 1) & (treeID !=6))
```

This works but as i have hundreds of treeId it is something not feasible.

How can i pass all my values from a list at once

Comment: does `!any(treeID %in% unlist(your_list_here))` work?

Comment: actually we wouldn't even need to `unlist` I just noticed :-)

Comment: Formalizing this to an answer @Purple_Ad, as you have the data and i-o the wisdom,  will be useful to future searchers as a lot more lidar data will be coming along...and people tend go to answered questions before they comb through comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the comment from I_O. I managed to make it work.

The code below will exclude the number of treeID that i dont want.

```
finallas <- filter_poi(las,!treeID %in% treeidlist)
```